# iOS App Crashes: Out of Memory despite ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have three entities User, LiveCard and LivePromos which I'm storing using Core Data.
When I read this data into memory and aggregate it into a single object, my app crashes and gives the error shown below.

```
User *user = (User *)[self getEntityWithName:@"User" andPopulator:@selector(populateUser:)];
if(user != nil)
{
    NSMutableArray *liveCards = [self getEntityWithName:@"LiveCard" andPopulator:@selector(populateLiveCard:)];
    [user setCards:liveCards];

    NSArray *livePromos = [self getEntityWithName:@"LivePromo" andPopulator:@selector(populatePromos:)];

    for(LiveCard *card in user.cards) {
        NSMutableArray *cardsPromo = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(LivePromo *promo in livePromos) {
            if([card.cardId isEqualToString:promo.cardId]) {
                [cardsPromo addObject:promo];
            }
        }
        card.promos = cardsPromo;
    }
}
return user;
```

This is the error I'm getting

> > MyApp(39516,0x3d38bb78) malloc: *** mmap(size=1935958016) failed (error code=12)
> >
> > *** error: can't allocate region
> >
> > *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

**NOTE:** I am using ARC in my application

**UPDATE**
I have already tried setting the `malloc_error_break` symbolic breakpoint and this is the screenshot of the Tread Navigator I get

http://postimg.org/image/x48p0m6df/

I also ran the Instrument.Allocations Utility on my application in iPhone Simulator, here is a screenshot which show large memory allocation in `malloc`. What I cannot understand is where this allocation is being made!

http://postimg.org/image/97v4zhszp/

*Sorry I couldn't upload images directly on SO*

**UPDATE** Thanks everyone for your inputs, the problem was that the UICollectionView was corrupted and the item count was in millions. The problem is now *RESOLVED*

Comment: 1. "despite ARC" - No, ARC is ***not*** a magical "make my app use less memory" feature. 2. Did you **read** the error message? You are trying to allocate 1935958016 bytes.

Comment: @H2CO3 As I understood it ARC is responsible for deallocating the objects created. MyApp is only reading some text data and it should never hit 1935958016 bytes at any single instance unsless they have been accumulating over time.

Comment: ARC is only responsible for inserting retain/release messages, instead of you writing them.

Comment: ARC != Garbage Collection. Turning on ARC doesn't absolve you of the need to be aware of reference counting. That said, this is probably NOT heap-growth due to over retained objects. The error indicated that it's one big allocation.

Comment: You are probably corrupting the heap, although it's possible something else is going wrong.  Anyway, when your app hits the breakpoint in `malloc_error_break`, copy the stack trace in the Thread Navigator.  Then come back here, edit your question, and paste in the stack trace.  What you called the “stacktrace” is just the disassembly of the `malloc_error_break` function, which is useless.

Comment: @robmayoff I have added the Thread Navigator screenshot to the question along with the instrumentation screenshot. Please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to be "obvious" but have you tried setting a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break`? It'll stop when it hits that function, and looking at the rest of the backtrace will show you what in your code is responsible for making this huge allocation.

Comment: I had already tried setting the breakpoint, I have updated my question to reflect the same. Please comment.

Comment: You're going to have to drag up the detail slider on that thread navigator. (at the bottom)

Comment: Done, updated image to include all details.

Comment: Something in the way you've configured UICollectionView is causing it to try to make this huge allocation. Given that this is happening in a method called `_updateItemCount` I would guess that perhaps there's too many items? Or maybe some sentinel value, like NSNotFound, is getting treated as a "real" value somewhere. There's not enough info here to tell, but the allocation is happening in `-[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]` so it's something about how you've configured a UICollectionView in your application.